# Angularjs $Resource GET Request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having some problems on making a request from angular to my Java backend.

My current code is this:

```
$scope.listdevices=function(){
        var devices = $resource('http://localhost:8080/userapi/devices/:userId',{userId:'@userId'});
        var list=devices.query({userId:$scope.userId});
        console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
        console.log(list);
        console.log(list.length+"TAMANHO")
};
```

The data is being being fetched and it looks like this:

[image]

But the objects are not being saved in my list when I call `listdevices`  to return a list of objects to iterate.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The question is not terribly clear, but it looks like you need to move some code into the query's success callback function (right now you're trying to do async code synchronously.)

Answer (score 0):

.query will be async, so you need a callback or a promise. Anyway, if you are trying to get a single record, you use "get". Here you have an example:

```
myApp.factory('Device', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8080/userapi/devices/:userId', {
    userId: '@userId'
  });
});

myApp.controller('YourCtrl', function(Device) {

  Device.get({
    userId: 1
  }).$promise.then(function(res){
    console.log(res)
  })
})
```

.query is for query your endpoint, for example if you wanted to search devices with conditions. Resource assumes that 'http://localhost:8080/userapi/devices' will return an array, while /:userId will return an object.

Extending the answer as per your comment, if you wanted to query a list of devices of a certain users (which returns an array), you would indeed use .query

```
Device.query({
  userId: 1
}).$promise.then(function(results) {

  console.log(results)

})
```

Alternatively, if you use a callback you have access to the headers.

```
Device.query({
  userId: 1
}, function(results, headers) {

})
```

Comment: hmm thanks for your help! But i still have some doubts.. the problem is that i want an array of devices from an user.. thats why the url has the userId as parameter..isnt that possible? thanks :)

Comment: I'd be careful suggesting arrow functions in JavaScript. It's entirely unsupported by IE.